# SKu is not defined error when uploading product

Tags: magento-1.9, sku

Hi can any one help me to fix this error I am not able to upload any product I am gating this error (`Line No 1 Skipping import row, required field "sku" is not defined.`) I am uploading the Sku like this **sku NAY101-Maroon** and image like this **nay101-maroon-_1__1.jpg** I am fade up while uploading this file can any one help me into that. my email is info@shoppingara.com

I tried like this also "**nay101-maroon**"

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice. If you want to add information, update the original question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it does not reflect the exact errors occurred during import.
Please check for the default required attributes like:

attribute_set, tax_class_id, weight, sku, name, price, description, short_description etc

check for extra spaces in the header row too.
while importing the images, please mention the source folder path in the import form in admin.